# Why does i get only the last row from the database?

Tags: java, netbeans

I use Netbeans 8.2. I'm trying to get data from the database and display it in a jTable.
But, when I run the program, I get the last row only.

Can anyone help me solve it?

```
public class MultiSpanCellTableExample extends JFrame {
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    Object [][]row;
    Object[] column;

    MultiSpanCellTableExample() {
        column = new Object[]{"","","","",""};  
        String g="",h="",j="",z="",n="",hg="",oo="",zz="";               
        Double l=null;
        Date i=null;
        String sql="SELECT  * from personn";                      
        con=Connections.getConnection();

        try{
            st=con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery(sql);                        
            while(rs.next()){                                        
                g=rs.getString("NAMME");                    
                l=rs.getDouble("TOTAL");                    
                i=rs.getDate("DATEE");                         
                z=rs.getString("WY");
                n=rs.getString("BAA");                                              
                row=new Object[][]{{g,l,z,i,n}};  
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print( e);
        }       

        AttributiveCellTableModel ml = new AttributiveCellTableModel(row,column);
        final CellSpan cellAtt =(CellSpan)ml.getCellAttribute();
        final MultiSpanCellTable table = new MultiSpanCellTable(ml);                  
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );                

        Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        box.add(scroll);
        box.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));
        box.add(p_buttons);
        getContentPane().add( box );
        setSize( 400, 200 );
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiSpanCellTableExample frame = new MultiSpanCellTableExample();
        frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the row in an array or a list, iterate the list, you will get everything.

Comment: In the while loop, each time you initialize row object and you did not store it in a array. Hence you get the last row when exiting the while loop.

Comment: Your issue is within the while loop - for each iteration of the loop, you process the rs.next and create a new row object. However, you never store the row object in a list or in the table, so the next iteration you replace the same row with a new one and end up only keeping the very last row.

Comment: @Sambit Thank you so much friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

You have not initialized `row[][]` with the required number of rows. Moreover, you are not storing the records into `row[i]`, where `i` is the index. Note that a 2-D array is an array of arrays and therefore each record from the database represent a 1-D array which needs to be stored into `row[i]`.

## Solution

```
try{
    // Get the number of rows
    Statment stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet rsCount = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT  count(*) from personn");

    if(rsCount.next()) {
        // Initialize row[][]
        row = new Object[rsCount.getInt(1)][];

        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);  

        for(int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {                                        
            g = rs.getString("NAMME");                    
            l = rs.getDouble("TOTAL");                    
            i = rs.getDate("DATEE");                         
            z = rs.getString("WY");
            n = rs.getString("BAA");  

            // Store the record into row[i]                                          
            row[i] = new Object[]{g,l,z,i,n};  
        } 
    }       
}
```